# Getting null response when passing select field array in SugarCRM

Tags: arrays, web-services, sugarcrm

I am trying to get_entry from Sugar-CRM using rest API v4_1.
When i tried passing value in select_fields I get null response..
When i passed empty select_fields array I get a successful response..

here's my code

```
    var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://mycrm.com/service/v4_1/rest.php",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "e85b8af0-3234-45c8-f5ec-abe8xx4d6efd",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "data": {
    "method": "get_entry",
    "input_type": "json",
    "response_type": "json",
    "rest_data": "{\"session\":\"xxyyxxsmkdemnmdm1212\",\"module_name\":\"Accounts\",\"id\":\"12345-6789-1214-1234\",\"select_fields\":{},\"link_name_to_fields_array\":{ }, \"track_view\":true}"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

the above code successfully gives me response when i pass empty array in select_fields..

**Note: I have changed my session,id,postman-token in above.. Those are not actual values.**

Comment: What values do you ask for in select_fields?

Comment: i want to pass only specific fields in select_fields for e.g. id,first_name,last_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `service/v3_1/SugarWebServiceImplv3_1.php` there the function `get_entry` for v4.1 of the api gets defined. As far as I see you should pass an array of fields.

They later get processed in `service/core/SoapHelperWebService.php` in function `get_name_value_list_for_fields` by a foreach.

Try 'select_fields':['id', 'name', ...]

Comment: Thanxx bro.. U are grt man... It worked like a magic.. Actually i was passing "{ }"  then I tried your method "[ ]"... It worked..